# Why not allow all users to up-vote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, upvotes, privileges

Stack Overflow only allows people to up-vote questions and answers if a certain reputation is achieved.  Considering that up-votes provide almost as much value as the original questions and answers, ignoring the potential up-votes of newbies to Stack Overflow is really preventing Stack Overflow from providing the higher level of quality that could otherwise be achieved.

What would be better?  Allow any and all users to up-vote anything except their own questions/answers.  Down-vote is a privilege to be earned, as this can easily be abused.  But up-votes are extremely valuable, even when they come from newbies to Stack Overflow.

An important negative side-effect of the current rule is that we end up with lots of redundant questions.  Since low reputation users cannot up-vote a stale but important unanswered question, they have no means of garnering attention for the issue except to ask another very similar question.  Nobody likes this, but what can they really be expected to do?

Comment: "Considering that up-votes provide almost as much value as the original questions & answers [...]" Upvotes and downvotes provide value but they do not provide "almost as much value as the original questions & answers", not even close.

Comment: "Down-vote is a privilege to be earned, as this can easily be abused" - Upvotes can be abused much more easily than downvotes, and arguably have a larger impact on the site.

Answer (score 26):

No, this is a *terrible* idea.

The limit is ridiculously low (15 rep). Its there to prevent users to make sure users have *some* idea of how the site works, and more importantly to prevent voting fraud.

Remove the limit and all I need to do is create a bunch of accounts to get unlimited rep.

Comment: "Voting irregularies" already make up a sizable portion of the suspended users list. I can't imagine how much more work it will be for the moderators if they took out that 15 rep barrier.

Comment: Then don't award rep for voting, that solves voting fraud problem.  The point is that voting is a big part of what provides value for the site.

Comment: @MattM How would you suggest getting reputation then? Upvotes are the primary way to do that. Even without reputation, being able to arbitrarily increase your score with much easier sock-puppets is going to be prone to abuse.

Comment: It would be a Sock Puppet apocalypse

Comment: @MattCoubrough You've got a great idea for a movie right there. You might submit it to SE, seeing as they now have something called Stack Overflow TV.

Comment: sigh - I see your point.  It never even occurs to me that people would want to abuse things like this.  How sad it is that we cannot trust ourselves & fellow humans with such simple things.  But we are what we are, and I agree with you guys now -- my suggestion was not a good one.

Comment: @MattM Gamification is definitely a two edged sword. Just one suggestion if you want a post to get more attention: edit it! Few posts are truly perfect. Editing will also bump the post to the top of the active page. Make you edit substantial of course, but that way you are improving the site *and* getting the question you want some eyeballs.